# ¿Como agregar un contador para obtener las veces que se ejecuta un método?

Tags: java, bucle-for, contador

Tengo el siguiente método en el cual se manda a llamar a otro método llamado **ejecutarPruebaServicio**, lo que necesito es saber cuantas veces se ejecuta ese método y pasarle ese valor al  **metodos.setPrueba("8");** posteriormente se actualiza ese valor y se compara en el último if, en caso de no ser igual las muestras, mandare un mensaje y se volverá a ejecutar el método **ejecutarPruebaServicio**, se vuelve a actualizar el contador y se vuelve a realizar la comparación hasta que sean iguales para poder ejecutar el servicio 2

como se le puede implementar un contador ? o que otra opción seria viable?

```html
public static void aplicarProceso(final ProcesoInType request,<String, ConfigProperty> mpConfigConfig,
                Map<Object, Object> frpMap) throws Exception {

            RepoUsuarios repositorio = OperacionesProceso.obtenerRepositorio(mpConfigConfig);
            String obtenerInfo = OperacionesProceso.obtenerInfo(request.getNumeroCliente(),mpConfigConfig, repositorio);
            if (obtenerInfo != null) {
                    String servicio = URL;
                    //Ejecutar AProceso
                    PruebaServicioA pruebaServ = new PruebaServicioA(request.getCampo1(), request.getCampo2,
                                        request.getCampo3),request.getCampo4), request.getNumeroCliente());

                           codigoReturn = ejecutarPruebaServicio(servicio, pruebaServ, estrategia, mpConfigConfig);
                            if (Codigo.EXITOSO.equals(codigoReturn)) {
                                
                                ClaseCache claseCache = new ClaseCache();
                                claseCache = OperacionesProceso.convertirJson(obtenerInfo);
                                if (obtenerInfo.contains(EnumTipo.PROCESO_ACTIVO.toString())) {
                                    for (MetodosProceso metodos : claseCache.getCache().getMetodosProceso()) {
                                        if (metodos.getTipoAutenticacion().equals(EnumTipoAutenticacion.VOZ_ACTIVA.toString())) {

                                               metodos.setPrueba("8"); //Contador del numero de veces que se ejecutar el metodo

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                

                                OperacionesProceso.actualizarCache(claseCache,request.getNumeroCliente(), repositorio);
                                String claseCacheNuevo = OperacionesProceso.obtenerClaseCache(request.getNumeroCliente(),mpConfigConfig, repositorio);
                                String pruebaObtenida = obtenerPruebas(claseCacheNuevo);

                                String pruebaConfiguradas = "3";
                                if(pruebaObtenida.equals(muestrasConfiguradas)){
                                    //EJECUTAR PROCESO 2
                                }
                            }

                    
            }

 }
```

Comment: Por favor, considera editar tu publicación y mejorar el formato del código, sobre todo en lo que se refiere a indentación, utilizando 4 espacios o un tabulador por nivel sintáctico (no 8 o 12 espacios como haces). De esta forma tus futuras publicaciones serán bien recibidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes declarar una variable estática:

```
public static int contadorDePruebaServicio = 0;
```

A esa variable le sumas 1 dentro del método `ejecutarPruebaServicio`

```
// Esta línea va dentro del método ejecutarPruebaServicio
// Al inicio o al final no hay diferencia, solo asegúrate
// de que no quede dentro de un if.
contadorDePruebaServicio++;
```

Ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Si el método es ejecutado desde múltiples procesos todas las ejecuciones se suman en la misma variable.
- En algún punto será necesario reiniciar el contador, por el contenido de la pregunta supongo que es luego de la comparación en el último if.

Answer (score 0):

No se si ese metodo se llama en modo safe o unsafe multihilos.
En caso que fuese el ultimo:

Opcion 1:

```
//Declara una variable global/estatica y volatile(para multihilos).
public static volatile int contador = 0;
public static void ejecutarPruebaServicio(){
contador++;
}
```

Opcion 2:

```
 //Declara una variable global/estatica.
    public static int contador = 0;
    //Utiliza el identificar sincronized para sincronizar las llamadas al metodo.
    public static synchronized void ejecutarPruebaServicio(){
    contador++;
    }
```

Opcion 3: En caso que sea safe no-multihilo.

```
 //Declara una variable global/estatica.
    public static int contador = 0;
  
    public static void ejecutarPruebaServicio(){
    contador++;
    }
```